# Accessing $_POST in php

Tags: php, android, http, post

I am developing an Android application which communicates with php on the server  side to access database. But to update the data when I use `POST` method, not able to get `$_POST` in the php, it has been empty. I tried with `postman`chrome plugin to see if its an issue with the application, but even in this case `$_POST` is empty. I am using php 5.2.

```
<?php

    echo "hello"; // Works fine.

    switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
    {
        case 'GET': echo "GET"; break;
        case 'POST': echo "POST"; break; // prints POST
        default: echo "DEFAULT";
    }

    echo $_POST; // Not printing as its empty
    if(empty($HTTP_POST_VARS ))
    {
        echo "POST EMPTY"; // This is printed
    }
...

?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the data on android side before sending that its not empty.

Comment: If the super global `$_POST` is empty in php, then no post arguments were provided. So either they were not sent at all, or they got lost in some proxy or rewriting step.

Comment: yes. I verified that. Also, I verified using postman chrome plugin wherein I can setthe parameters,  HTTP method etc and check the output

Comment: A really wild guess: check your php.ini configuration: it might be that (whyever) you have this setting enabled: `enable_post_data_reading = Off`

Comment: Check the webserver access log to see if the app is indeed making a POST as it ought to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can return all request parameters like this, this way you can see what you are recieving on the server side:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

If its empty, then youre not sending anything

Comment: What is the benefit of this? If `$_POST` is empty, then it is empty. The values will not magically appear in `$_REQUEST` then.

Comment: maybe hes using the wrong HTTP verb, this would disclose such oversights

Comment: The OP will see exactly what was chosen in the postman attempt. So no new information there.